# rails 3 and ajax: set action how?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a create.js.erb, I want make this: if the user click to create button, the site load index partial.

```
$('.content').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "events/index")) %>");
```

If I use this, I get error @objectname.each is wrong, I think it's empty, because in the create.js.erb file I only call the partial, and I think I must call index method somehow. It's right?

```
    def create
    @event = Event.create(params[:event])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to(events_url) }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.js
      end
    end
end
```

the error message:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for #<Event:0x00000102182830>):
    1: - @event.each do |events|
    2:   %h3.title= events.name
```

Comment: show your create action in controller

Comment: def create
    @event = Event.create(params[:event])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to(events_url) }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.js
      end
    end
end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the partial with the events it should be rendering. Right now you're just providing it with the single event, `@event.` Populate `@events` if the action is a success then update events/_index to call `@events.each` instead of `@event.each`.

```
def create
  @event = Event.create(params[:event])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @event.save
      format.html { redirect_to(events_url) }
      format.js {
        @events = Event.all
      }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```